# Post installation hardware detection?

Tags: 16.04, hardware

I did a clean install of 16.04 on this laptop (HP Elitebook 2760p) and it detected all the quirky buttons on it.

Then I swapped out that HDD for an SSD that had 16.04 also on it, but was installed when the drive was in a Dell machine.

Now, the buttons are not detected by keyshow or xev as they were with the previous fresh installation. So something that runs at install time picks up the hardware. Is it possible to make whatever 'this' is pick up on the extra buttons now?

Comment: On 14.04, under "System Settings," if you go to "Software and Updates," there's a tab for available drivers. Is there something similar on 16.04?

Comment: Hi tihingan. There is something for microcode on Intel processors, but that's it. Someone has suggested I compare the packages from the two system as it's likely the support was provided in the form of an installed package. I'm going to try that next time I have both machines.